# Using functions only one time

Tags: function, conventions

Is it a good idea to put code (to e.g. read a file for only one time) in a function even though i will call the function only once? That seems more overseeable to me than just putting the whole code into the main function. I'm not sure if that matches the common conventions.

Comment: You can do either. Typically it is considered a good practice to split extra long functions into other functions for readability. On the other hand if you want to optimize the performance of your code to a max, you may want to avoid extra function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the code to a separate function for sure if -

```
-It enhances legibility
-It is a logically separable chunk of code.
```

Function calls would be an overhead if only you make too many calls(maybe from within a loop) and do very little within the function itself. Only in such a case refrain from carving out a function.